# Robust Estimators - Winsorized Variance degree of freedom (df)

Tags: variance, robust, winsorizing

this is my first question on this site.

So, I'm currently working on my final year thesis, and it was on Robust statistics. In my work, I will use Trimmed Mean, Winsorized Mean and Winsorized Variance. However, from many online source, the df for Winsorized Variance is different when it's paired with Trimmed mean as corresponding scale estimator.

Here goes the two version:
Eq. 1
$$\hat\sigma_w^2 = \frac {1}{n-1} \sum (w_i - \hat\mu_w)^2$$
where n = total number of observation in the winsorized distribution

Eq. 2
$$\hat\sigma_w^2 = \frac {1}{n-2g-1} \sum (w_i - \hat\mu_w)^2$$
where n = total obs, g = no. of obs to be trimmed.

The question is, everytime I see Trimmed Mean and Winsorized Variance, the df=n-2g-1 (the one in Eq. 2), but whenever I see Winsorized Variance standalone, the df=n-1 (the one in Eq. 1). Therefore, anyone here has any clarification?